# Prove that block diagonal matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Suppose that $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, \dotsc, A_{k} $ are square matrixes. Define: $$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
  A_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  0 & A_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & A_k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
prove that $ A $ is invertible if and only if $A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3}, \dotsc, A_{k} $ are invertible.

Comment: Are you familiar with row reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $$det(A)=det(A_1)\cdot det(A_2) \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot det(A_k)$$

Comment: Proving the hint is harder than using it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a really easy way to show that a matrix is invertible is to write down the inverse explicitly. For instance, the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{20 & 0 \\ 0 & \pi}
$$
is invertible, and the proof is that
$$
\pmatrix{\frac{1}{20} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\pi}}
$$
is its inverse, which I can show by multiplying them. Can you think of something you'd multiply the block matrix
$$
\pmatrix{
A_1 & 0 \\
0 & A_2
}
$$
by to get the identity? Perhaps you might want to work this out by inversion-by-hand in the case where
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{6}
$$
and
$$
A_2 = \pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ 
1 & 4}
$$
for instance, and see whether you notice anything.